# Any idea why .addClass doesn't apply? jQuery

Tags: jquery, addclass

```
(function (){

var stones = parseInt($('body').attr('data-site')) + 1,
    theul = $(".submenu > ul li:nth-child(" + stones + ")");

    console.log(theul);
    $('theul').addClass('active');
    console.log(theul);
})();
```

Logs shows the exact same thing before and after adding the class.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, it should be:

```
theul.addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply do

```
var stones = parseInt($('body').attr('data-site')) + 1,
    theul = $(".submenu > ul li:nth-child(" + stones + ")");

    console.log(theul);
    theul.addClass('active');
    console.log(theul);
})();
```

Because  `$('theul').addClass('active');` would add the class `active` to elements of the ipotetical tag `theul`

Answer (score 0):

It should be theul.addClass('active');